# is MongoDb mapreduce to another collection more memory efficient than `out inline`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm running `MongoDb` on an instance with 512 meg of RAM, (along with some other web apps) so every megabyte counts

[MongoDb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-cmd) states that `out: { inline: 1 }`

> Perform the map-reduce operation in memory and return the result.

which suggests that other out types don't perform in memory.. Would it be more memory efficient to return `mapReduce` results into another collection - provided that in the end I would still need to read that collections data to return it to client

Answer (score 2):

Considering that inline can only really be usefull when Map Reduce is called from an application I should state that Map Reduce is not designed to be run inline your application and you should try and convert over to the aggregation framework or something else if you can.

The inline out is limited to 16MB (single BSON document). Considering this you may find that actually is is slower to write out to a collection and then read that collection again rather than just do it all in memory.

Comment: Ah yes, inline is limited to max doc size. Forgot that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing to another collection and then later reading from it does not require holding whole dataset in memory (where by "dataset" I mean that set of aggregated data). It can be safely written to / read from a disk.

When you're using "out: inline", it is stored in memory in its entirety. If there's not enough memory, some swapping/paging-out will occur.

Anyway, to get good performance numbers you should have enough memory to hold all hot data. Disk is slow.

In light of all that, inline or not inline, it probably makes little difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: yes, definitely more memory efficient to have `mapReduce` store the results in a collection.

If you use `inline`, the results of the MR operation will be returned as an array, which means all results are stored in memory before being handed to the calling code. If you store the results in a collection instead, you can use cursors or streams to prevent having to read everything into memory before returning to the client.